# Can we call two actionresult/controller at once in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Can we call Two ActionResult /Controller function at once which both return partial view?

Comment: Do you mean rendering two partial views at the same page?

Comment: both action at once ! I dont think so, but you can call actions in sequence before a view is returned.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

No you can't call two actions at the same time using one URI.  This is because the routing table will only match one route and then pass execution to that controller and action.  You can call another action from within that action, but I wouldn't recommend it and would just have your client send another request to the server for that other action you want to run.