# How to download multiple pdf files from various mvc actionresult using single actionlink razor view without zipped

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view, controller

I have 2 various action results returning 2 pdf files. I need to call both 2 actions from single actionlink mvc razor view

My actionresults like this

`public ActionResult ExportFirstPDF() { my code}`
`public ActionResult ExportFirstPDF() { my codes}`

My Action link like this

```
` @Html.ActionLink(" ", "ExportAllPDF", new{id=1})`
```

OR

I will use any other common action I donot know how to call both actions.

Can anyone help me please. both PDF files wanna download as separate files without zipped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844973/can-we-call-two-actionresult-controller-at-once-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put common action button to rise a dialog box. 
In dialog box I set separate action buttons with dynamic parameters. [click to view PDF common button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0wQL.png)

My dialog box look like this [click to view Dialog box - having independent buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itSls.jpg)

This will avoid the zip work, end user also happy with this process